# System Verilog inside operator operands bit length

Tags: system-verilog

How "inside" sub-expressions bit lengths are supposed to be computed in System Verilog?
It appears that the type of an expression depends on whether an operand is a numeric literal or a variable.

The following System Verilog program:

```
`define M( x ) $display( `"x -- %b`", x )

module top ();

  bit [3:0] a, b;

  initial begin
    // (a+b) could be evaluated either to 0 or 16, depending on the bit length of the expression.

    a = 15;
    b = 1;

    `M(4'd1 inside { [(a+b):17] } );  // 0
    `M(4'd1);
    `M(   b inside { [(a+b):17] } );  // 1
    `M(   b);

  end

endmodule
```

outputs:

```
Chronologic VCS simulator copyright 1991-2019
Contains Synopsys proprietary information.
Compiler version P-2019.06-SP1-1_Full64; Runtime version P-2019.06-SP1-1_Full64;  May  8 20:27 2020
4'd1 inside { [(a+b):17] } -- 0
4'd1 -- 0001
b inside { [(a+b):17] } -- 1
b -- 0001
           V C S   S i m u l a t i o n   R e p o r t 
Time: 0
CPU Time:      0.250 seconds;       Data structure size:   0.0Mb
Fri May  8 20:27:08 2020
```

PS: Verific interprets the standard differently from Synopsys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a tool bug that it produces different results for two different operands of the same value and width.

However, the correct answer is slightly ambiguous because the `inside` operator was left out of *Table 11-21—Bit lengths resulting from self-determined expressions* in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM. This is a [reported issue](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=1805) for the LRM, and the consensus is that is should behave the same as the `case inside` statement in that all operands get sized to the largest size operand before doing any comparisons. In this example, the literal `17` is 32-bits wide and has the largest width. So the result of the `inside` operator should be `1'b0`.